# Post Processing Aggregates

Tags: python

I have a question for a data analysis question where I need to separate data into two groups: months and states.

The task involves as:

> In any given month, the minimum monthly rainfall for each state is the lowest rainfall recording from any weather station in that state during that month.
>
> For example, suppose NSW had recordings of 1, 10, 5, and 7 for January; then its minimum monthly rainfall for January would be , the lowest of those recordings.
>
> If there are several correct answers, your program can output any of the correct answers.

On the given data, the program's output should look like this:

```
Month: 11
State: QLD
```

What I have tried is:

```
minimum_monthly_rainfall = {}
is_first_line = True

for row in open("climate_data_2017.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
    is_first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    month = values[0].split("-")[1]
    rainfall = float(values[6])
    state = values [1]

    if month in minimum_monthly_rainfall:
      minimum_monthly_rainfall[month].append(rainfall)
    else:
      minimum_monthly_rainfall[month] = [rainfall]


print(minimum_monthly_rainfall)
```

I am not sure as what to do now. I have skipped the first line of the data file which i will show below, and I have discriminated all the monthly rainfall into corresponding months. However I am not sure how I will separate this back into months? I know I shoul

The data file is:

```
Date,State,City,Station Code,Minimum temperature (C),Maximum temperature (C),Rainfall (mm),Evaporation (mm),Sunshine (hours),Direction of maximum wind gust,Speed of maximum wind gust (km/h),9am Temperature (C),9am relative humidity (%),3pm Temperature (C),3pm relative humidity (%)

2017-06-03,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.9,14.3,0,,,SSW,19,10.8,76,13.1,73
2017-06-04,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.5,19.7,1.4,0.6,6.8,W,28,12.2,77,19,57
2017-06-04,QLD,Brisbane,40913,12.8,22.6,0.6,1.8,9.1,ENE,31,16.3,77,22.5,52
2017-06-04,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4.4,15.8,0,,,NE,13,5.7,100,15.5,53
2017-06-05,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.4,19.6,0.5,2.8,9.4,W,28,11.5,78,19.2,41
2017-06-05,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.1,25.3,0.6,1.8,9.2,ENE,31,15,71,24.9,30
2017-06-05,VIC,Melbourne,86338,5.6,17.5,0,,,NW,28,8.7,82,16.8,57
2017-06-06,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.1,17.9,0.5,2.2,7.2,WSW,59,11.2,58,14.7,43
2017-06-06,QLD,Brisbane,40913,9.2,25.2,0.6,2.4,7.7,N,41,17.9,38,24.5,13
2017-06-06,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.7,13.9,6.4,,,SSW,43,11.8,78,12.6,68
2017-06-07,NSW,Sydney,66062,8.8,15.5,54.6,2.6,0,SSW,56,13.3,82,14.2,85
2017-06-07,QLD,Brisbane,40913,5,22.8,0.6,4.4,9.1,SE,31,12.4,68,22.5,39
2017-06-07,VIC,Melbourne,86338,5.9,14.3,0,,,SE,28,8.3,91,14,54
2017-06-08,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.4,18.1,61,1.8,1.3,SE,44,13.3,91,16.9,84
2017-06-08,QLD,Brisbane,40913,9.9,22.5,0.6,2.2,9.2,ENE,48,13,75,22.1,25
2017-06-08,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3.6,15,0,,,SSW,30,6.6,86,14,56
2017-06-09,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.4,18.9,3.4,1.6,4.8,ESE,52,12.5,90,18.2,64
2017-06-09,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.7,24.1,0.6,4.8,9.3,NE,37,15.8,27,23.8,14
2017-06-09,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6.6,15,1.8,,,S,22,11,98,13.9,66
2017-06-10,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.5,18.1,38.8,3.6,0.2,SSE,50,15.8,85,17.5,70
2017-06-10,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.7,20.8,0.6,3.8,1.9,NNE,33,14.7,33,20.4,25
2017-06-10,VIC,Melbourne,86338,7,15.8,0,,,SSW,17,7.5,100,14,68
2017-06-11,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.5,17.2,2.8,1.6,0.2,WNW,20,13.1,90,16,85
2017-06-11,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.4,23.5,0.6,3.2,4.5,ENE,41,13.6,33,23.4,14
2017-06-11,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3.4,15.5,0.2,,,SSW,22,6.1,96,13.6,67
2017-06-12,NSW,Sydney,66062,11.3,20.4,1.2,0.8,7.5,SSE,26,11.6,92,19.1,59
2017-06-12,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.1,24,0.6,3.8,7.6,NNE,39,16.7,26,23.7,22
2017-06-12,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6,15.9,0,,,SSW,19,10,85,15,77
2017-06-13,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.5,18.7,0.5,2.2,9.1,SSE,37,11.2,82,18.2,62
2017-06-13,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.8,24.8,0.6,3.4,5.6,NE,28,15,35,22.4,24
2017-06-13,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.8,15.1,0,,,WSW,20,10.7,88,13.4,67
2017-06-14,NSW,Sydney,66062,11.1,17.8,2.6,1.8,2.9,WNW,24,13.3,82,17.4,78
2017-06-14,QLD,Brisbane,40913,12.1,20.4,14.6,3.4,4.3,E,37,14.2,83,19.4,63
2017-06-14,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4,17.4,0,,,N,28,7.8,97,16.7,56
2017-06-15,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.7,20.1,0.6,1.2,6.4,W,22,11.9,89,18.7,69
2017-06-15,QLD,Brisbane,40913,9.9,19.3,0.6,3.2,6.5,SSW,24,14.7,87,18.1,65
2017-06-15,VIC,Melbourne,86338,7.7,19,0,,,N,20,9.8,87,17.4,53
2017-06-16,NSW,Sydney,66062,11.9,17.3,0.5,1.6,0.2,WNW,26,13.3,79,17.2,69
2017-06-16,QLD,Brisbane,40913,6.6,20.8,0.6,1,8.3,S,22,12.1,85,20.2,43
2017-06-16,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6.6,17.1,0,,,NNE,15,8.4,86,15.9,65
2017-06-17,NSW,Sydney,66062,13.2,19.1,0.5,1,0.2,SSW,26,14.6,81,17.4,67
2017-06-17,QLD,Brisbane,40913,5,21.7,0.6,2.4,9,E,39,13.1,78,21.5,47
2017-06-17,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4.2,15.5,0,,,NE,15,5.4,95,14.9,66
2017-06-18,NSW,Sydney,66062,11.3,18,1.8,2,6.3,S,52,12.9,83,17.6,62

2017-07-02,NSW,Sydney,66062,5.4,17.6,0.5,2,9.5,W,28,7.6,78,16.1,44
2017-07-02,QLD,Brisbane,40913,3.9,15,20,1.6,4.2,S,35,7.3,90,14.2,46
2017-07-02,VIC,Melbourne,86338,0.8,14.3,0,,,N,41,3.8,75,13.9,36
2017-07-03,NSW,Sydney,66062,5.6,15.8,0.5,2.6,2.7,N,31,7.9,81,15.4,57
2017-07-03,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7,16.6,0.6,2,4.6,NNW,31,8.9,82,15.2,58
2017-07-03,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3.8,13.9,0,,,NNE,39,9,60,11.2,92
2017-07-04,NSW,Sydney,66062,7.9,21.8,0.2,0.6,9.3,,,13.2,76,21.5,23
2017-07-04,QLD,Brisbane,40913,5.5,14.4,2,1.4,1.2,N,19,8.3,94,13.9,73
2017-07-04,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9,16.2,3,,,N,33,11,78,15.6,54
2017-07-05,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.2,20.8,0.5,5.4,9.2,W,52,14.4,51,18.7,36
2017-07-05,QLD,Brisbane,40913,8,13.9,3.4,1.8,2.8,SW,59,11.9,92,10.7,83
2017-07-05,VIC,Melbourne,86338,10.1,15.8,0,,,SSW,24,12.4,75,13.4,65
2017-07-06,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.1,18.2,0.5,4.8,9.7,WSW,37,11.5,62,17.4,36
2017-07-06,QLD,Brisbane,40913,4.7,16,10.4,4.2,5.5,WNW,30,7.4,88,14.4,60
2017-07-06,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4.8,15,0,,,N,28,8.1,75,14.1,46
2017-07-07,NSW,Sydney,66062,6.6,19.1,0.5,3.6,9.4,WNW,35,8.8,73,18.6,24
2017-07-07,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.4,17.6,9.8,1,6.9,SW,33,11.6,97,16.2,59
2017-07-07,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8,14.2,0,,,NNW,37,9,79,13.4,56
2017-07-08,NSW,Sydney,66062,7,18.1,0.5,3.2,9.3,W,37,9,66,17,36
2017-07-08,QLD,Brisbane,40913,3.2,17.2,0.6,1.4,9,S,28,10.2,83,16.5,41
2017-07-08,VIC,Melbourne,86338,5.3,13.5,0,,,NW,30,9,84,13.2,58
2017-07-09,NSW,Sydney,66062,7.4,18,0.5,2,9.5,W,33,9.2,69,17.6,33
2017-07-09,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.1,17.8,0.6,2.4,7.4,NE,22,10.4,68,17.4,42
2017-07-09,VIC,Melbourne,86338,7.3,14.6,0.8,,,NNW,39,9.7,70,13.3,49
2017-07-10,NSW,Sydney,66062,7,17.3,0.5,3.6,9.4,W,39,9.4,67,16.7,36
2017-07-10,QLD,Brisbane,40913,5.9,17.9,0.6,2.4,4,NNE,39,12.5,52,17.6,40
2017-07-10,VIC,Melbourne,86338,7,16,0,,,W,28,9.2,74,15.2,48
2017-07-11,NSW,Sydney,66062,6.6,18.4,0.5,2.8,9.2,SSW,39,9,63,17.7,46
2017-07-11,QLD,Brisbane,40913,12.5,19.7,0.6,2.6,4.2,WNW,52,15.6,52,18.5,78
2017-07-11,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6.9,14.3,0.4,,,NW,19,9.8,79,13.8,57
2017-07-12,NSW,Sydney,66062,7.8,14.8,1.6,3.4,0.5,W,31,8.9,76,13,79
2017-07-12,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.8,20.4,3.4,2.4,8,NW,61,18,69,19.2,59
2017-07-12,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3.2,15.1,0,,,N,30,4.8,89,14.7,49
2017-07-13,NSW,Sydney,66062,8,17.4,10.4,1,9.3,ENE,30,9.6,80,17.2,49
2017-07-13,QLD,Brisbane,40913,13.2,18.6,7.2,3.6,3,SW,33,15.1,96,18.1,60
2017-07-13,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4.8,13.3,0,,,N,56,10.9,56,13,54
2017-07-14,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.6,20.8,0.5,4,6.1,NNW,30,12.2,67,19.3,41
2017-07-14,QLD,Brisbane,40913,12.3,19.2,0.4,2.8,2.3,NE,24,14.6,76,18.1,62
2017-07-14,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.9,15.9,2,,,N,50,10.5,76,15.2,41
2017-07-15,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.1,19.8,0.4,4,6.1,SW,30,13,71,17.9,39
2017-07-15,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.4,19.9,0.6,2.6,1.3,WNW,50,14,96,16.9,82
2017-07-15,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4.5,12,0,,,NW,22,7.8,71,11.6,58
2017-07-16,NSW,Sydney,66062,7.7,18.4,0.5,1.8,9.4,WSW,31,9.4,61,16.8,32
2017-07-16,QLD,Brisbane,40913,13.7,19.2,4.6,2,3.6,SW,37,15.8,66,18.1,45
2017-07-16,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3,12.5,0,,,N,52,5.7,75,11.1,54
2017-07-17,NSW,Sydney,66062,7.9,19.3,0.5,4.2,6.5,W,24,9.8,75,17.3,44
2017-07-17,QLD,Brisbane,40913,8.7,19.2,0.6,3.4,9.1,NE,33,12.4,64,18.5,41
2017-07-17,VIC,Melbourne,86338,5.7,15.3,0,,,N,52,11.8,55,14.6,50
2017-07-18,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.1,22.9,0.5,1.2,9.8,NW,54,14.1,62,22.6,30
2017-07-18,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.2,24.6,0.6,3.2,9.2,N,46,14.8,52,24.1,35
2017-07-18,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.7,14.5,0.2,,,NNW,41,10.6,75,13.8,55
2017-07-19,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.6,17.5,0.5,6.6,9.1,WSW,57,12,53,16.9,33
2017-07-19,QLD,Brisbane,40913,13.2,18.7,8.4,3.8,3,N,61,14,96,14.1,89
2017-07-19,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.9,13.2,5,,,SSW,37,10.8,99,11.6,81
2017-07-20,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.3,17.5,0.5,4.4,9.6,WSW,63,11.4,55,15.8,26
2017-07-20,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.5,18.2,18.4,3.6,7.7,WSW,56,15.3,69,16.4,71
2017-07-20,VIC,Melbourne,86338,7.9,10.7,0.6,,,SSW,39,9.4,82,9.7,77
2017-07-21,NSW,Sydney,66062,7.5,18,0.5,4.2,9.2,W,46,9.6,53,17.4,37
2017-07-21,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.6,20.1,5,0.6,7,NW,59,13.2,88,18.6,53
2017-07-21,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3.3,13.8,4.2,,,N,26,5.8,93,13.4,53
2017-07-22,NSW,Sydney,66062,6,19.1,0.5,3.6,9.8,W,31,7.9,64,18.7,27
2017-07-22,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.7,19.3,6.1,,4.5,WSW,31,12.4,97,17.8,55
2017-07-22,VIC,Melbourne,86338,5.4,12.4,0,,,N,59,8.4,65,11.6,54
2017-07-23,NSW,Sydney,66062,6.5,22.1,0.5,3.6,9.9,NW,44,10.8,49,22.1,22
2017-07-23,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.7,18.1,2.3,6.6,4.8,N,50,13.4,93,18,66
2017-07-23,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.4,14.1,0,,,N,44,10.2,57,11.3,90
2017-07-24,NSW,Sydney,66062,10,21.3,0.5,7.2,9.6,WSW,31,12.7,51,20.9,24
2017-07-24,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10,18.6,16.8,4.2,3.9,W,39,12.4,95,17.1,50
2017-07-24,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.1,16.1,7,,,WSW,28,9.9,77,15.2,53
2017-07-25,NSW,Sydney,66062,7.9,20.6,0.5,4.2,9.9,NW,30,11,63,19.7,32
2017-07-25,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.4,19.6,3,0,3.4,NW,39,13,96,18.7,53
2017-07-25,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.8,17.2,0,,,N,48,11.1,72,16.4,53
2017-07-26,NSW,Sydney,66062,11,21.3,0.5,2.8,9.9,W,70,18,39,20.2,27
2017-07-26,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.7,19.2,0.4,2.2,3.1,SW,48,15.6,78,17.4,73
2017-07-26,VIC,Melbourne,86338,10.9,15,2.4,,,SW,37,12.5,70,12.7,71
2017-07-27,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.1,17.5,0.5,4.8,9.7,W,31,11.2,61,17.1,44
2017-07-27,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.6,21.5,24,1.8,6.5,NNW,59,14.5,90,19.4,68
2017-07-27,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4.4,14.2,2,,,N,52,6.2,90,13.8,55
2017-07-28,NSW,Sydney,66062,11.2,19.1,0.5,4.2,8.3,WSW,67,13.1,51,18.9,25
2017-07-28,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.5,17.7,10.8,3.4,,WNW,78,17,60,13.9,83
2017-07-28,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6.2,14.3,2.8,,,NNE,37,10.9,73,13.4,56
2017-07-29,NSW,Sydney,66062,8.2,21.2,0.5,4.6,9.9,W,31,10.7,52,20.9,23
2017-07-29,QLD,Brisbane,40913,9.7,15.1,11.2,6.8,5,WSW,72,12.1,77,12.3,86
2017-07-29,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.7,17.9,0,,,N,81,12.7,51,16.9,41
2017-07-30,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.7,26.5,0.5,6,6.2,NNW,44,18.4,25,24.8,22
2017-07-30,QLD,Brisbane,40913,5.3,17.1,9.8,1.6,6.5,WSW,33,11.1,79,15.4,52
2017-07-30,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.3,18.1,0,,,NW,31,13.7,64,17.5,34
2017-07-31,NSW,Sydney,66062,15.6,16.5,0.5,4.4,0,WSW,56,15.7,72,11.8,85
2017-07-31,QLD,Brisbane,40913,9.5,15.7,0.6,2.2,0.6,WSW,67,12.3,75,12.8,81
2017-07-31,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6.7,14.8,0,,,S,19,9,79,13.7,56
2017-08-01,NSW,Sydney,66062,8.6,18.1,6,2.4,9.8,SW,39,11.6,57,16.9,39
2017-08-01,QLD,Brisbane,40913,1.8,15.3,23.8,2.6,9,SSW,39,8.4,87,14.2,53
2017-08-01,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3.5,15.5,0,,,SSW,20,6.2,89,13,64
2017-08-02,NSW,Sydney,66062,7.2,18.2,0.5,3.2,8.8,S,41,9.6,62,16.8,51
2017-08-02,QLD,Brisbane,40913,1,14.9,0.6,0.6,9.7,E,26,8.7,81,14.3,47
2017-08-02,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3.4,12.9,0,,,NNE,13,5.6,100,12.8,61
2017-08-03,NSW,Sydney,66062,8.9,17.4,3,2.8,5.5,NNE,37,10.3,85,16.4,70
2017-08-03,QLD,Brisbane,40913,3.6,17.9,0.2,1.8,2.1,W,54,8.5,87,14.3,96
2017-08-03,VIC,Melbourne,86338,3.1,9,0,,,NNE,15,4.3,89,8.7,84
2017-08-04,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.3,17.3,13.8,1.8,10.2,W,50,12.8,60,16.6,41
2017-08-04,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.9,15.5,1.6,2,1,WSW,30,10.3,77,14.3,64
2017-08-04,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4.3,12.1,6.6,,,N,50,8.9,87,11.5,66
2017-08-05,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.6,19.9,0.5,5.6,10.1,WNW,48,14,46,19.3,22
2017-08-05,QLD,Brisbane,40913,9.3,18.3,0.4,1.6,6.1,WSW,31,12.4,94,16.8,59
2017-08-05,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.8,14.2,0,,,N,52,10.6,68,13.1,55
2017-08-06,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.1,21.3,0.5,6.8,9.9,NW,54,15,46,20.9,26
2017-08-06,QLD,Brisbane,40913,6.7,19.8,0.6,3.2,6.1,NW,37,11.8,81,19.4,41
2017-08-06,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9,13,0,,,NNE,54,10,76,11.7,54
2017-08-07,NSW,Sydney,66062,13.5,18.4,0.5,6.8,9.8,W,63,14.7,44,16.9,25
2017-08-07,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.6,19.4,0.6,2.4,0.8,N,30,14.5,78,18.4,65
2017-08-07,VIC,Melbourne,86338,7.7,12.3,4.2,,,SW,41,9.4,70,11,79
2017-08-08,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.7,19.3,0.5,7.2,10.3,WSW,54,12.1,45,18.5,24
2017-08-08,QLD,Brisbane,40913,12.5,19.2,0.4,2,2.3,NW,57,15.9,82,14.8,93
2017-08-08,VIC,Melbourne,86338,7.9,15,2.2,,,NW,26,10.5,72,13.9,59
2017-08-09,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.2,20.9,0.5,5,10.4,W,33,12,53,20,32
2017-08-09,QLD,Brisbane,40913,8.5,14.7,43.6,4.4,3,SW,72,9.7,93,11.6,63
2017-08-09,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.9,16.8,0,,,N,46,11.4,74,15.1,60
2017-08-10,NSW,Sydney,66062,9.2,24.2,0.5,4,9.4,NNW,31,11.8,64,23.5,24017-09-10,NSW,Sydney,66062,8,19.1,0.5,5,10.8,W,24,13.5,52,17.3,51
2017-09-10,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.6,20.8,0.2,4.6,4.7,W,30,14.6,91,20.3,46
2017-09-10,VIC,Melbourne,86338,5.3,16.1,0.2,,,N,20,10.8,76,16,47
2017-09-11,NSW,Sydney,66062,8.7,22.7,0.5,3.8,10.1,NE,24,14.4,60,22.5,29
2017-09-11,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.2,19.6,5.2,4.4,5.6,WSW,41,16.4,94,17.8,73
2017-09-11,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.1,18.1,0,,,N,46,12.7,63,16.9,50
2017-09-12,NSW,Sydney,66062,11.3,27.2,0.5,5.8,2.3,E,26,18.2,43,23.4,34
2017-09-12,QLD,Brisbane,40913,13.2,19.4,1.4,4.2,7.9,SW,54,15.9,68,19,35
2017-09-12,VIC,Melbourne,86338,12.2,19.9,0.2,,,NNW,39,15.2,60,19.7,59
2017-09-13,NSW,Sydney,66062,18.2,33.8,0.5,6.2,9.6,NNW,70,24.9,19,32.5,10
2017-09-13,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.7,21.6,0.6,6.4,11,E,43,13.3,50,21.6,27
2017-09-13,VIC,Melbourne,86338,13.3,16.4,2,,,WSW,50,14.9,62,11.7,69
2017-09-14,NSW,Sydney,66062,12,17.3,0.2,13,10.5,WSW,72,13.8,37,16.4,26
2017-09-14,QLD,Brisbane,40913,6.3,25.6,0.6,6,7,WSW,30,17.2,34,24.1,27
2017-09-14,VIC,Melbourne,86338,5.8,15.3,1.4,,,W,43,9.6,66,14.1,56
2017-09-15,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.5,22.8,0.5,7.8,10.6,W,52,16.6,37,22.2,24
2017-09-15,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.5,27.8,0.6,4.6,8.5,ENE,37,17.6,43,27.6,26
2017-09-15,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.6,16.7,0,,,WSW,35,13.5,58,14.8,82
2017-09-16,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.5,24.2,0.5,7,6.4,SSW,56,17.3,43,21.3,22
2017-09-16,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.9,24.4,0.6,4.8,6.5,WSW,33,15,96,21.9,48
2017-09-16,VIC,Melbourne,86338,7.4,13.3,21.4,,,SSW,54,9.1,81,12.5,52
2017-09-17,NSW,Sydney,66062,8.1,18.6,0.5,4.6,10.8,ESE,28,13.6,48,16.4,37
2017-09-17,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.6,21.7,0.4,4.4,9.6,WSW,33,18.5,72,21.1,47
2017-09-17,VIC,Melbourne,86338,4,18.1,0.2,,,N,43,10.5,58,17.8,35
2017-09-18,NSW,Sydney,66062,8.2,21,0.5,5.6,10.7,NE,39,14,55,20.2,55
2017-09-18,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.6,26,0.6,4,10.4,E,37,15.8,71,25.7,34
2017-09-18,VIC,Melbourne,86338,10.5,22,0,,,NNW,63,15.7,32,20.9,30
2017-09-19,NSW,Sydney,66062,14,25.2,0.5,6.4,10.8,SSW,54,20.4,30,23.1,16
2017-09-19,QLD,Brisbane,40913,8.9,22.4,0.6,7,8.5,WSW,31,17.9,73,21,67
2017-09-19,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9,13.9,0.2,,,WNW,31,11.6,58,12.4,58
2017-09-20,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.7,19,0.5,9.2,7.7,WSW,33,14.6,44,17.7,56
2017-09-20,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.7,21.4,5.4,4.6,6.9,W,48,18,57,20.6,52
2017-09-20,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6,19.2,0,,,N,35,11.6,63,18.6,42
2017-09-21,NSW,Sydney,66062,10.4,21.3,0.5,3.8,10.1,NE,30,15.6,65,21.2,49
2017-09-21,QLD,Brisbane,40913,16.8,21.5,5.8,5,3.4,NW,81,19.8,72,19,61
2017-09-21,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.6,23.6,0,,,N,54,14.8,46,22.4,33
2017-09-22,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.8,27.7,0.5,7.2,10.5,NNE,35,20.1,35,25.8,26
2017-09-22,QLD,Brisbane,40913,13,19.2,7.4,5.2,1.9,W,89,14.5,88,17.3,58
2017-09-22,VIC,Melbourne,86338,12.8,25.6,0,,,N,33,14.9,71,24.8,32
2017-09-23,NSW,Sydney,66062,15.5,32.2,0.5,8.6,5.7,NNE,50,23,25,29.1,25
2017-09-23,QLD,Brisbane,40913,11.4,17.1,9.8,5.4,5.3,SW,52,13.4,72,16.1,48
2017-09-23,VIC,Melbourne,86338,14.8,30.6,0,,,N,61,21.1,30,30,24
2017-09-24,NSW,Sydney,66062,23,29.2,0.5,12,6.5,W,54,27.1,20,27.8,15
2017-09-24,QLD,Brisbane,40913,10.1,17.3,5.2,4.4,4.5,NNW,46,14.8,75,14,87
2017-09-24,VIC,Melbourne,86338,12.9,19.9,0.4,,,NNW,56,14.9,56,18.4,40
2017-09-25,NSW,Sydney,66062,16,26.7,0.5,10.8,10.8,WNW,57,22.3,21,23.3,19
2017-09-25,QLD,Brisbane,40913,9.3,17,10.4,3.2,4.6,NE,35,11.8,81,14.9,67
2017-09-25,VIC,Melbourne,86338,10.3,14.2,1.6,,,SSW,35,12.9,64,12.8,68
2017-09-26,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.3,22.2,0.5,9.6,11,WSW,41,19.5,29,19,47
2017-09-26,QLD,Brisbane,40913,6,18.2,3.4,4.4,9.3,WSW,41,13.1,69,17.5,40
2017-09-26,VIC,Melbourne,86338,5,15.1,0.4,,,S,24,11.3,64,14,46
2017-09-27,NSW,Sydney,66062,15.4,22.7,0.5,6.6,8.2,ENE,50,18.1,58,21.1,62
2017-09-27,QLD,Brisbane,40913,5,16.7,0.6,6.8,5.6,SW,41,13.1,58,14.7,56
2017-09-27,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.6,24.6,0,,,NNW,50,12.5,64,24.5,30
2017-09-28,NSW,Sydney,66062,18,25.7,0.5,6.2,3.8,WNW,59,22.7,47,24.1,26
2017-09-28,QLD,Brisbane,40913,6.9,16.6,1,3.4,3.5,WSW,33,12.7,72,13.5,76
2017-09-28,VIC,Melbourne,86338,10.4,18.5,0,,,SW,35,14.1,66,16.8,45    2017-10-01,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.7,17.2,0,,,S,24,12.4,65,16.4,58
2017-10-02,NSW,Sydney,66062,12,22.9,0.5,6.2,10.1,NE,44,16.7,55,21.3,60
2017-10-02,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.7,24,0.6,4.8,11.3,WSW,39,19.6,43,22.1,45
2017-10-02,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.5,16.4,0,,,SSW,24,12.1,75,15.2,58

2017-10-15,NSW,Sydney,66062,16,22.4,0.5,3.8,2.4,ESE,28,22.3,52,20.1,58
2017-10-15,QLD,Brisbane,40913,16.4,25.4,0.6,7.2,11.6,W,33,20.4,61,22.4,53
2017-10-15,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6.8,17.6,0,,,SSW,31,12.4,67,16.7,67
2017-10-16,NSW,Sydney,66062,15.9,23.3,0.5,5,10.4,E,30,22.4,55,22.3,50
2017-10-16,QLD,Brisbane,40913,15.3,19.9,3,5.8,6.5,NW,91,15.8,91,18.2,51
2017-10-16,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.3,28.6,0,,,NNE,28,12.9,91,26.2,40
2017-10-17,NSW,Sydney,66062,16.9,23.5,0.5,7.6,9.9,ENE,39,21.2,57,22.9,47
2017-10-17,QLD,Brisbane,40913,13.9,20.1,7.6,5.4,5.8,WNW,52,17,71,19.8,50
2017-10-17,VIC,Melbourne,86338,12.8,30.2,0,,,N,37,21,50,30.1,24
2017-10-18,NSW,Sydney,66062,18.8,23.2,0.5,9,10.4,NNE,50,20.9,64,22.5,56
2017-10-18,QLD,Brisbane,40913,12,19.4,5,5,11.7,SW,44,16.7,46,18.2,37
2017-10-18,VIC,Melbourne,86338,14.5,30.9,0,,,NNW,48,21.7,43,29.9,31
2017-10-19,NSW,Sydney,66062,17.1,25.3,0.5,10,11.4,NNE,52,22.1,52,24.6,47
2017-10-19,QLD,Brisbane,40913,6.8,24.7,0.6,6.4,12.1,E,56,16.8,44,24.4,24
2017-10-19,VIC,Melbourne,86338,21.7,25.6,0,,,SW,43,23.8,45,23.5,71
2017-10-20,NSW,Sydney,66062,19,19.6,7.8,9.2,0,S,56,19.6,87,15.3,85
2017-10-20,QLD,Brisbane,40913,12.1,29.9,0.6,6,12.1,E,61,22.3,31,29.4,17
2017-10-20,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.3,16.2,2.6,,,S,41,13.4,69,15.3,56
2017-10-21,NSW,Sydney,66062,13,20,16.4,4.4,11.3,SSW,50,16.8,52,18.9,53
2017-10-21,QLD,Brisbane,40913,15.9,29.5,0.6,9.2,4.9,ENE,65,23.2,32,28.2,26
2017-10-21,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11,15.4,0,,,S,28,11.8,71,14.8,63
2017-10-22,NSW,Sydney,66062,13.4,21.7,0.2,4.8,5.5,ESE,30,16,75,18.7,60
2017-10-22,QLD,Brisbane,40913,18.5,28.4,1.2,7.2,11.7,E,70,23.1,56,27.1,46
2017-10-22,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.1,16,0,,,SSW,28,12.7,78,15.2,76
2017-10-23,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.7,23,3.4,3.6,12.1,S,31,18,60,22.1,43
2017-10-23,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.3,23.6,0.6,5.6,3.8,WSW,37,18.2,80,22.4,57
2017-10-23,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.9,19,0,,,SSW,31,13.6,72,17.3,61
2017-10-24,NSW,Sydney,66062,13.9,24.3,0.5,6.8,10.5,NE,39,19.9,57,22.6,55
2017-10-24,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.3,22.6,0.6,6.2,11,W,37,18.2,63,20.3,40
2017-10-24,VIC,Melbourne,86338,12.1,20.5,0.2,,,SSW,26,15,74,17.4,61
2017-10-25,NSW,Sydney,66062,18,26.9,0.5,8,5,S,59,21,67,23.3,56
2017-10-25,QLD,Brisbane,40913,9.6,22.7,0.6,7,7.3,W,44,19,69,21.7,54
2017-10-25,VIC,Melbourne,86338,13.3,18.5,11.4,,,SSW,24,14.5,94,17.3,67
2017-10-26,NSW,Sydney,66062,17.2,24.6,0.4,7,6.5,WSW,63,19.7,73,22.6,63
2017-10-26,QLD,Brisbane,40913,13.3,20.9,1.2,4.6,5.3,WNW,67,17.6,77,16.4,66
2017-10-26,VIC,Melbourne,86338,12.9,16.8,0.2,,,SSW,39,13.8,83,15.5,73
2017-10-27,NSW,Sydney,66062,14.8,24.2,34.2,7.2,3.9,WSW,61,18.1,85,22.3,65
2017-10-27,QLD,Brisbane,40913,8.4,19.3,2,6.2,4.8,WSW,44,16.7,48,17.5,51
2017-10-27,VIC,Melbourne,86338,10.3,27.4,0,,,N,48,15.1,78,25.2,37
2017-10-28,NSW,Sydney,66062,17.5,25.1,0.2,3.2,7.7,ENE,35,21.6,66,22.3,65
2017-10-28,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14,20.5,1,4.2,6.2,WSW,52,18.4,54,19.8,54
2017-10-28,VIC,Melbourne,86338,15,21.4,0.4,,,N,39,15.4,72,19.7,46
2017-10-29,NSW,Sydney,66062,20.2,29.6,0.2,4.6,10.6,NNE,39,24.4,49,27.7,35
2017-10-29,QLD,Brisbane,40913,12.6,20.6,0.8,4.2,11.6,SW,54,16.7,46,19.9,41
2017-10-29,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.5,28.6,0,,,N,61,19,63,27.4,25
2017-10-30,NSW,Sydney,66062,20.3,35.4,0.5,11.4,9.3,SSW,69,28.5,37,34.9,13
2017-10-30,QLD,Brisbane,40913,7.9,27.5,0.6,6.8,12.5,WSW,35,19.1,44,25.9,33
2017-10-30,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.8,17,4.4,,,W,46,12.6,62,14.4,55
2017-10-31,NSW,Sydney,66062,13,20.5,0.5,12,10.1,SSE,57,15.8,43,19.7,36
2017-10-31,QLD,Brisbane,40913,8.7,29.3,0.6,10.4,12.2,SW,39,20.2,54,27.1,35
2017-10-31,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.1,16.4,6,,,S,28,12,62,15.4,48
2017-11-01,NSW,Sydney,66062,13,22.2,0.5,9.6,4.2,SSW,54,15.4,39,21,32
2017-11-01,QLD,Brisbane,40913,15,30.5,0.6,10.4,10.4,SE,44,21.5,48,29,39
2017-11-01,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.9,18,0.4,,,SSW,26,14.7,78,15.8,66
2017-11-02,NSW,Sydney,66062,15.3,22.6,0.5,5.6,9.9,ESE,31,20.1,56,21.8,46
2017-11-02,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.7,27.6,0.6,10.2,11.9,E,46,19.4,51,27,35
2017-11-02,VIC,Melbourne,86338,11.3,17.4,1.4,,,SSE,26,12.7,79,15.9,56
2017-11-03,NSW,Sydney,66062,16.9,26.9,0.5,6.6,5.9,SSW,57,20.6,58,25.7,48
2017-11-03,QLD,Brisbane,40913,13.6,26.9,0.6,9.8,12.3,ESE,43,19.5,49,25.3,41
2017-11-03,VIC,Melbourne,86338,9.4,16.6,1.4,,,S,46,12,58,15.3,45
2017-11-04,NSW,Sydney,66062,16.2,17.1,1.6,7.4,0,SSE,39,17,73,15.8,78
2017-11-04,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.8,30.7,0.6,8,12.6,E,69,23.1,43,30.3,20
2017-11-04,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.3,15.8,0.4,,,SSW,35,10.2,72,14.5,47
2017-11-05,NSW,Sydney,66062,14.1,19.5,31.8,2.6,0,ENE,39,14.9,85,17.7,59
2017-11-05,QLD,Brisbane,40913,15.2,31.1,0.6,10.2,12.6,E,67,21.6,38,31,20
2017-11-05,VIC,Melbourne,86338,6.4,17.6,0,,,SSW,39,13.4,59,15.6,49
2017-11-06,NSW,Sydney,66062,14.8,26.3,4.4,1.8,5.7,SSW,67,19.4,81,23.6,57
2017-11-06,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.9,32.7,0.6,10.2,12.5,E,67,23.5,33,32.7,11
2017-11-06,VIC,Melbourne,86338,10.9,16.1,0,,,S,43,13.8,66,14.8,60
2017-11-07,NSW,Sydney,66062,13.8,21.8,5.6,8.8,11.3,SSE,54,18.9,40,20,40
2017-11-07,QLD,Brisbane,40913,17.3,36.4,0.6,12,12.5,E,59,27.1,21,35.4,14
2017-11-07,VIC,Melbourne,86338,10,15.8,3.4,,,S,43,12.2,76,14.4,52
2017-11-08,NSW,Sydney,66062,14.6,21.7,0.5,9.6,10,SSE,44,16.8,54,20.5,44
2017-11-08,QLD,Brisbane,40913,20,35.6,0.6,11.2,10.8,ENE,37,28,30,33.1,24
2017-11-08,VIC,Melbourne,86338,12.1,16.9,0,,,S,30,13.9,59,15.6,64
2017-11-09,NSW,Sydney,66062,12.3,22.1,0.5,6.8,11.6,E,28,17.9,52,21.2,50
2017-11-09,QLD,Brisbane,40913,15.2,31.6,0.6,7.8,12.8,SW,37,26.9,42,29.7,31
2017-11-09,VIC,Melbourne,86338,8.7,21.8,0,,,SSW,28,14.6,68,18.1,66
2017-11-10,NSW,Sydney,66062,14.2,23.4,0.5,6.8,11.6,E,26,19.2,59,22.7,50
2017-11-10,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.1,32,0.6,8.4,12.6,W,33,26.4,41,30.1,37
2017-11-10,VIC,Melbourne,86338,12.1,27.2,0,,,SE,20,15.7,78,22.8,63
2017-11-11,NSW,Sydney,66062,14.7,23.7,0.5,7.4,8.6,ENE,33,19.9,58,20.9,56
2017-11-11,QLD,Brisbane,40913,16.2,38,0.6,9,10,W,41,30.4,32,33.5,27
2017-11-11,VIC,Melbourne,86338,14.8,24.7,0,,,SSW,26,17.8,79,22,65
2017-11-12,NSW,Sydney,66062,17.1,22.5,0.5,7.4,10.7,E,31,19.7,49,21.7,47
2017-11-12,QLD,Brisbane,40913,22.4,32.1,0.6,11.8,11.3,S,39,28.7,39,28.8,46
2017-11-12,VIC,Melbourne,86338,13.2,23.3,0,,,SSW,28,16.1,86,21.6,69
2017-11-13,NSW,Sydney,66062,17.5,22.3,0.5,6.4,9.1,E,33,19.1,48,21.2,42
2017-11-13,QLD,Brisbane,40913,17.5,30.1,0.6,10.2,12.7,SW,50,25.2,65,27.9,45
2017-11-13,VIC,Melbourne,86338,13.7,33,0,,,NE,24,19.3,73,32,20
2017-11-14,NSW,Sydney,66062,16,22.9,0.5,7.6,8.9,ENE,37,20,53,22.3,46
2017-11-14,QLD,Brisbane,40913,14.5,29.7,0.6,11.8,12.7,SE,54,20.2,47,29.1,19
2017-11-14,VIC,Melbourne,86338,18.2,33.9,0,,,N,48,25.3,38,33.1,27
```